# Scapy custom DHCP Option82

Tags: scapy, dhcp

I'm trying to create a custom DHCP request with Option82 included but I'm not able to set the length of the suboption:

```
ethernet= Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',src=get_if_hwaddr("eth1"), type=0x800)
ip= IP(src='0.0.0.0', dst='255.255.255.255')
udp = UDP(sport=68, dport=67)
bootp = BOOTP(chaddr =hw, ciaddr ='0.0.0.0', xid =0x01020304, flags= 1)
dhcp = DHCP(options=[("message-type","discover")])/DHCP(options=[("relay_agent_Information", "TEST"), "end"])

packet = ethernet / ip / udp / bootp / dhcp
```

No matter what I do, option82 always has the wrong length. Does any body know how to set the address header of the suboption?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

DHCP Option 82 isn't a simple string like `"TEST"`. You may find a very nice explanation of the option in [RFC3046](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3046.txt) DHCP Option 82 is a "container" option for specific agent-supplied sub-options. The format of the Relay Agent Information option is:

```
      Code   Len     Agent Information Field
     +------+------+------+------+------+------+--...-+------+
     |  82  |   N  |  i1  |  i2  |  i3  |  i4  |      |  iN  |
     +------+------+------+------+------+------+--...-+------+
```

The length N gives the total number of octets in the Agent Information Field.  The Agent Information field consists of a sequence of SubOpt/Length/Value tuples for each sub-option, encoded in the following manner:

```
      SubOpt  Len     Sub-option Value
     +------+------+------+------+------+------+--...-+------+
     |  1   |   N  |  s1  |  s2  |  s3  |  s4  |      |  sN  |
     +------+------+------+------+------+------+--...-+------+
      SubOpt  Len     Sub-option Value
     +------+------+------+------+------+------+--...-+------+
     |  2   |   N  |  i1  |  i2  |  i3  |  i4  |      |  iN  |
     +------+------+------+------+------+------+--...-+------+
```

`Scapy` doesn't work with suboptions so you need to supply the complete Option 82 field in hexadecimal format, including field length etc. As an example, consider the following modification to your code that yields the correct length of Option 82:

```
...
option82 = "\x01\x01\x05\x02\x06\x11\x22\x34\x44\x55\x66"
dhcp = DHCP(options=[("message-type","discover")])/DHCP(options=[("relay_agent_Information", option82), "end"])
...
```

In this particular case DHCP Option 82 is `\x01\x01\x05\x02\x06\x11\x22\x34\x44\x55\x66`. Here the `Circuit ID = 05` and`Remote ID = 112233445566`. The corresponding Wireshark dump is below:

[image: Wireshark dump of the packet]